# date_select having indentation issues in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <%= label_tag 'Production_Month' %>
      </div>
      <div  class="col-lg-2">:</div>
      <div  class="col-lg-2"></div>
      <div  class="col-sm-4">
          <%= date_select(:params, :production_month, order: [:month, :year]) %>         
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am using the above date_select in one of my forms.

I have 2 questions here:

1. The indentation of the date select seems to be right justified as shown below. How do I change it to left justified?

[image: date select indentation issue]

2. Currently the year dropdown seems to display a list of -5 to +5 years from current year. How do I change it to display the list of years available in a model (say `MyYears` instead)?

Answer (score 0):

I think following comtainers make the mess:

```
      <div  class="col-lg-2">:</div>
      <div  class="col-lg-2"></div>
```

In this way you can display year in specific range:

```
<%= date_select(:params, :production_month, order: [:month, :year], start_year: 2010, end_year: 2020) %>
```

Comment: If I add a normal `select_tag`, that displays left justified as I expect. But `date_select` gets right justified. So I am curious to know how to left justify `date_select` just like `select_tag`